# Problem with automatic SMS service using curl

Tags: php, post, curl, http-headers

@edit:

fixed everything and decoded the view state and this is what I got now, still isn't working, it takes me to a html with all these functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Page_ValidationSummaries =  new Array(document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar"));
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD"), document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD"), document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone"), document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone"), document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem"));
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD");
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD.controltovalidate = "ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumDDD";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD.focusOnError = "t";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD.errormessage = "DDD";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD.display = "None";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD.validationGroup = "Enviar";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD.initialvalue = "";
var ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD");
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD.errormessage = "DDD com 2 dígitos";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD.display = "None";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD.validationGroup = "Enviar";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD.evaluationfunction = "CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD.clientvalidationfunction = "ValidarDDD";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD.validateemptytext = "true";
var ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone");
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone.controltovalidate = "ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumTelefone";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone.focusOnError = "t";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone.errormessage = "Telefone";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone.display = "None";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone.validationGroup = "Enviar";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone.initialvalue = "";
var ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone");
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone.errormessage = "Telefone com 8 dígitos";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone.display = "None";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone.validationGroup = "Enviar";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone.evaluationfunction = "CustomValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone.clientvalidationfunction = "ValidarTelefone";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone.validateemptytext = "true";
var ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem");
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem.controltovalidate = "ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtMensagem";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem.focusOnError = "t";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem.errormessage = "Mensagem";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem.display = "None";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem.validationGroup = "Enviar";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem.initialvalue = "";
var ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar = document.all ? document.all["ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar"] : document.getElementById("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar");
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar.headertext = "Campos de preenchimento obrigatório:";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar.showmessagebox = "True";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar.showsummary = "False";
ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar.validationGroup = "Enviar";
//]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.add_load(FirejQuery);

var Page_ValidationActive = false;
if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {
    ValidatorOnLoad();
}

function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
    if (Page_ValidationActive) {
        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_ValidationSummaries, document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_vsEnviar'));
}
Sys.Application.initialize();
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbCpfCnpj"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFCNPJ"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbCPFAlterarCadastro"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFAlterarCadastro"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbDDDAlterarCadastro"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtDDDAlterarCadastro"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbTelefoneAlterarCadastro"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtTelefoneAlterarCadastro"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbCPFAlterarCadastroNC"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFAlterarCadastroNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbDDDAlterarCadastroNC"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtDDDAlterarCadastroNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbTelefoneAlterarCadastroNC"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtTelefoneAlterarCadastroNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbCEP1AlterarCadastroNC"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCEP1AlterarCadastroNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbCEP2AlterarCadastroNC"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCEP2AlterarCadastroNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbCPFEsqueciSenha"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFEsqueciSenha"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbCPFAlterarSenha"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFAlterarSenhaNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbSenhaAtualAlterarSenhaNC"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtSenhaAtualAlterarSenhaNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbNovaSenhaAlterarSenhaNC"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNovaSenhaAlterarSenhaNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbConfirmeNovaSenhaAlterarSenhaNC"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtConfirmeNovaSenhaAlterarSenhaNC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbNumDDD"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumDDD"));
});

document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumDDD'));
}

document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvDDD'));
}
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ftbNumTelefone"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumTelefone"));
});

document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvNumTelefone'));
}

document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_ctvTelefone'));
}

document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl00_Blank_ctl00_rfvMensagem'));
}
//]]>
</script>
</form>
    <!-- START OF SmartSource Data Collector TAG -->

    <script src="/nextelwebsite/js/webtrends.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var _tag=new WebTrends();
        _tag.dcsGetId();
        //]]>>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        // Add custom parameters here.
        //_tag.DCSext.param_name=param_value;
        _tag.dcsCollect();
        //]]>>
    </script>

    <noscript>
        <div>
            <img alt="DCSIMG" id="DCSIMG" width="1" height="1" src="http://sdc.nextel.com.br/dcslz078000000wgujjv96o3y_8x7v/njs.gif?dcsuri=/nojavascript&amp;WT.js=No&amp;WT.tv=8.6.2" /></div>
    </noscript>
    <!-- END OF SmartSource Data Collector TAG -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/nextelwebsite/js/Common.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my current code:

```
<?php
include('pegaForms.php');
echo pegaMaterias();
function pegaMaterias()
{
$header = array("Host:  nextel.com.br", "Proxy-Connection:  keep-alive", "Referer:  http", "Content-Length:  3382", "Origin:  http", "Cache-Control:  no-cache", "X-MicrosoftAjax:  Delta=true", "User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1 Paros/3.2.13", "Content-Type:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", "Accept:  */*", "Accept-Encoding:  sdch", "Accept-Language:  en-US,en;q=0.8", "Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3", "Cookie: cAtm=a; ASP.NET_SessionId=wmqaqt55yswgyd45a31avb45; WT_FPC=id=139.82.60.168-3061391072.30168743:lv=1313586431216:ss=1313584965026");
$array_parametros = array();
$array_parametros['ctl00_ScriptManager1'] = "ctl00\_Blank\_ctl00\_upSMS|ctl00\_Blank\_ctl00\_lkbEnviarSMS";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_hidUpdate'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtTipoCliente'] = "S";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtAlert'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtjQuery'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtFleetID'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtSenhaIndividual'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFCNPJ'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtSenha'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_caracteres'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtFleetIDAlterarCadastro'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFAlterarCadastro'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNomeAlterarCadastro'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtEmpresaAlterarCadastro'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtDDDAlterarCadastro'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtTelefoneAlterarCadastro'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtEmailAlterarCadastro'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFAlterarCadastroNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNomeAlterarCadastroNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtEmpresaAlterarCadastroNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtDDDAlterarCadastroNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtTelefoneAlterarCadastroNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCEP1AlterarCadastroNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCEP2AlterarCadastroNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtEmailAlterarCadastroNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtFleetIDEsqueciSenha'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtEmailEsqueciSenha'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFEsqueciSenha'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtCPFAlterarSenhaNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtSenhaAtualAlterarSenhaNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNovaSenhaAlterarSenhaNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtConfirmeNovaSenhaAlterarSenhaNC'] = "";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumDDD'] = "21";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumTelefone'] = "number";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtMensagem'] = "banana phone";
$array_parametros['ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtContador'] = "108";
$array_parametros['__EVENTTARGET'] = "ctl00\_Blank\_ctl00\_lkbEnviarSMS";
$array_parametros['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = "";
$array_parametros['__VIEWSTATE'] = "5381
/NextelWebSite/NextelControls/wfGeraImagem.aspx?27b18018-88e1-4f2c-8f7a-e1d1a50497d4=zq9I&t=7032
MoveNext(0, 'ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumDDD', 'ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumTelefone', event);
MoveNext(0, 'ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumDDD', 'ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumTelefone', event);
MoveNext(0, 'ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumTelefone', 'ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtMensagem', event);
MoveNext(0, 'ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtNumTelefone', 'ctl00_Blank_ctl00_txtMensagem', event);
120";
$array_parametros['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = "";
$array_parametros['__ASYNCPOST'] = "true";
//$array_parametros = format_postfields($array_parametros);
//echo $array_parametros;
$ch = curl_init();
$URL = "http://nextel.com.br/NextelWebSite/produtos/mensagens/sms/enviar_conteudo_copy1.aspx";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_parametros);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
return $ret;
}

?>
```

Comment: Just as a note, you can pass an array into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: I dont need to join parameters with an & ?

Comment: No, check the manual - "This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few of problems I see

*) Values are url encoded

this should be 
ctl00%24Blank%24ctl00%24txtTipoCliente => ctl00$Blank$ctl00$txtTipoCliente

You can use this to correct the parameters
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ or run them through php [urldecode](http://se.php.net/urldecode)

*) The part after the equal should go in the value

this

$array_parametros['ctl00%24Blank%24ctl00%24txtTipoCliente=S'] = "";

should be

$array_parametros['ctl00$Blank$ctl00$txtTipoCliente'] = "S";

*) ASP.NET and ViewState encryption

The __VIEWSTATE suggest the server is using ASP.NET and the VIEWSTATE is likely encrypted. This means it might be very difficult to accomplish what you are trying withough getting sessionid/cookies.

I am guessing but I believe the error page you are getting is due to view state validation failing but I could be wrong. Try to fix the request parameters as described above and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, your guess was correct, i decoded it with an online view state decoder.

Comment: Well, I decoded the viewstate, fixed up everything, figured out that $ is a underline in asp.net or whatever and it still using working, I edited the main post with my current code, can you help me ?

Comment: remove the equal sign

$array_parametros['ctl00%24Blank%24ctl00%24txtTipoCliente='] = "S";
=>

$array_parametros['ctl00%24Blank%24ctl00%24txtTipoCliente'] = "S";